# CruiseControl.NET ForceBuild is not really using build parameters

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to pass dynamic parameters to ForceBuild. But CruiseControl.NET seems to be ignoring those parameters, at least two of clients --  CruiseServerHttpClient and CruiseServerRemotingClient.  Here `ForceBuildClient2()` and `ForceBuildClient3()` forces build but parameters are ignored by CruiseControl.

Whereas the third client -- CruiseServerClient() is throwing error. Here `ForceBuildClient1()` throws an exception --"`The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`"

Please, help me to resolve this. The code is as follows:-

```
 void ForceBuildWithParameters
   {
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new List<NameValuePair>();

            NameValuePair nvPair = new NameValuePair();
            nvPair.Name = "BetaLinkVersion";
            nvPair.Value = "TTS_WB_Suite_14.1.23";
            parameters.Add(nvPair);

            NameValuePair nvPair2 = new NameValuePair();
            nvPair2.Name = "SmartVersion";
            nvPair2.Value = "smtone_smtone";
            parameters.Add(nvPair2);

            bool bAsRequest = false;

            var request = new IntegrationRequest(BuildCondition.ForceBuild, "WIN-O1GHG0JM8MC", "balasubramaniam.ramasamy");
            request.BuildValues.Add("BetaLinkVersion", "TTS_WB_Suite_14.1.23");
            request.BuildValues.Add("SmartVersion", "smtone_smtone");

            ForceBuildClient1(parameters, bAsRequest, request); // Not working
            ForceBuildClient2(parameters, bAsRequest, request);
            ForceBuildClient3(parameters, bAsRequest, request);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }


    private void ForceBuildClient1(List<NameValuePair> parameters, bool bAsRequest, IntegrationRequest request)
    {
        HttpConnection connection = new HttpConnection("http://localhost/ccnet");
        CruiseServerClient client = new CruiseServerClient(connection);

        if (!bAsRequest)
            client.ForceBuild("Package Beta Link", parameters); // Not working
        else
            client.Request("Package Beta Link", request); // Not working
    }

    private void ForceBuildClient2(List<NameValuePair> parameters, bool bAsRequest, IntegrationRequest request)
    {
        CruiseServerRemotingClient client = new CruiseServerRemotingClient("tcp://t1devbuild.int.thomsonreuters.com:21234/CruiseManager.rem");

        if (!bAsRequest)
            client.ForceBuild("Package Beta Link", parameters);
        else
            client.Request("Package Beta Link", request);
    }

    private void ForceBuildClient3(List<NameValuePair> parameters, bool bAsRequest, IntegrationRequest request)
    {
        var client = new CruiseServerHttpClient(string.Format("http://{0}/ccnet/", "t1devbuild.int.thomsonreuters.com"));

        if(!bAsRequest)
            client.ForceBuild("Package Beta Link", parameters);
        else
            client.Request("Package Beta Link", request);
    }
```

Comment: Seems a slight code change give a workaround...
CruiseServerClient client = new CruiseServerClientFactory().GenerateClient("tcp://example.com:21234/CruiseManager.rem") as CruiseServerClient;